# Is it well-defined to use memset on a dynamic bool array?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing, memset

Is this code well-defined behavior, in terms of strict aliasing?

```
_Bool* array = malloc(n);
memset(array, 0xFF, n);
_Bool x = array[0];
```

The rule of effective type has special cases for `memcpy` and `memmove` (C17 6.5 §6) but not for `memset`.

My take is that the effective type becomes `unsigned char`. Because the second parameter of `memset` is required to be converted to `unsigned char` (C17 7.24.6.1) and because of the rule of effective type, (C17 6.5 §6):

> ...or is copied as an array of character type, then the effective type
>   of the modified object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the
>   value is the effective type of the object from which the value is copied, if it has one.

- Question 1: What is the effective type of the data stored in `array` after the `memset` call?
- Question 2: Does the `array[0]` access therefore violate strict aliasing? Since `_Bool` is not a type excluded from the strict aliasing rule (unlike character types).

Comment: Even if a comparison like `array[0] == true` is not often used and considered to verbose, I think it should still be valid. And with your `memset` call that comparison will actually be *false*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This goes deeper than just the value comparison. If there is UB because of strict aliasing violation, the compiler is free to give `x` any value, or crash and burn for that matter.

Comment: I would think the effective type is still `_Bool`, however, the representation in the memory may not be valid. Possibly `memset(array,(unsigned char)false, n);` would make it valid.

Comment: That's true, so maybe I should have waited for an answer to that before bothering about petty details like that. :)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie What do you mean "still _Bool"? How did it end up _Bool? The pointer returned by malloc has no effective type yet. And the cast in your memset example is superfluous, check 7.24.6.1.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was thinking the type is `_Bool *` so the memory will be interpreted as `_Bool`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie No, unfortunately C doesn't work like that. Dynamically allocated memory does not get a type before a value is stored inside it.

Comment: While I see you refer C17, is it really a different question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970251/what-is-the-effective-type-of-an-object-written-by-memset ?

Comment: According to this logic, memsetting an allocated block to `0` and reading `int`s out of it would also be UB.  IMO that would not have been anyone's intent, and this is yet another case of the strict aliasing rule being woefully underspecified.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `(unsigned char)false` has value `0` and not `1`. And effectively the cast serves nothing since when passing the argument, it is converted to `int`, anyhow.

Comment: @tevemadar It seems very similar, but the answer there isn't too convincing.

Comment: @JensGustedt ops :D indeed. I somehow supposed that setting to 0xFF was supposed to set it to true, hence I read `(unsigned char)true`. `errno == ENOCOFEE`

Comment: Related [Is it safe to memset bool to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33380742/1708801)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `memset` does *not* change the effective type. [C11 (C17) 6.5p6:](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6)

   > 6. The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is
   >      the declared type of the object, if any. *[ This clearly is not the case. An allocated object has no declared type. ]*
   >
   >    If a value is stored into
   >      an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that
   >      is **not a character type**, then the type of the lvalue becomes the
   >      effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent
   >      accesses that do not modify the stored value. *[ this is not the case as an lvalue of character type is used by `memset`! ]*
   >
   >    If a value is **copied**
   >      into an object having no declared type using `memcpy` or `memmove`, or **is
   >      copied as an array of character type**, then the effective type of the
   >      modified object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do
   >      not modify the value is the effective type of the object from which
   >      the value is copied, if it has one.
   >      *[ this too is not the case here - it is not copied with `memcpy`, `memmove` or an array of characters ]*
   >
   >    **For all other accesses to an
   >      object having no declared type, the effective type of the object is
   >      simply the type of the lvalue used for the access.** ***[ therefore, this has to apply in our case. Notice that this applies to accessing it as characters inside `memset` as well as dereferencing `array`. ]***

   Since the values are stored *with* an `lvalue` that has character type inside `memset`, and not *have the bytes copied from another object with lvalues of character type* (the clause exists to equate `memcpy` and `memmove` with doing the same with an explicit `for` loop!), it does not get an effective type, and the effective type of elements is `_Bool` *for those accessed through `array`*.

   There might be parts in the C17 standard that are underspecified, but this certainly is not one of those cases.
2. `array[0]` would not violate the effective type rule.

   That does not make using the value of `array[0]` any more legal. It can (and will most probably) be a trap value!

   I tried the following functions

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdbool.h>        

   void f1(bool x, bool y) {
       if (!x && !y) {
           puts("both false");
       }
   }


   void f2(bool x, bool y) {
       if (x && y) {
           puts("both true");
       }
   }

   void f3(bool x) {
       if (x) {
           puts("true");
       }
   }

   void f4(bool x) {
       if (!x) {
           puts("false");
       }
   }
   ```

   with `array[0]` as any of the arguments - for the sake of avoiding compile-time optimizations this was compiled separately. When compiled with -O3 the following messages were printed:

   ```
   both true
   true
   ```

   And when without any optimization

   ```
   both false
   both true
   true
   false
   ```

Comment: So, effectively, `_Bool` behaves as a *one-bit-float*

Comment: @joop effectively no. It behaves like... an integer... except that it does not.

Comment: I meant: with respect to trap representations.

Comment: @joop `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: I'm not following 1). As per the mentioned C17 7.24.6.1, memset should be regarded as subsequent writes of `unsigned char` type(?). Or why should it not? So the first part that you formatted bold should not apply, but rather the part quoted in the question? Though I guess in either case, the effective type is never _Bool so it would be a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @Lundin but the effective type clause says that the effective type is only changed when the are *copied* from another object with an lvalue of a character type. Then they become "type of lvalue of the originator". This is not the case here.

Comment: *when the bytes of the object are copied